# odoo calculate age from a date field and today date

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to get an age between a field and today date

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from openerp import SUPERUSER_ID
from datetime import date

class report_purchase_stock(models.Model):
_name='report.purchase.stock'

etaw_update = fields.Date('ETA Warehouse') // 2022-01-24
etaw_age = fields.Char('Days in Warehouse')
```

I have tried something like this from the forum but it return empty

```
@api.onchange('etaw_update')
def set_age(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.etaw_update:
            dt = rec.etaw_update
            d1 = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            d2 = date.today()
            rd = relativedelta(d2, d1)
            rec.etaw_age = str(rd.years) + ' years'
```

What I want is something like 1 month 14 days

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `etaw_update` is a date where the product entering warehouse for the first time, and `etaw_age` is the total days where that product has been stored. Is that right?

If that so, you may want to define a `current_date` variable which will get the todays date, and then you can subtract that `current_date` with `etaw_update`

```
@api.onchange('etaw_update')
  def set_age(self):
    for rec in self:
     current_date = date.today()
     date_in_your_field = rec.etaw_update

     rec.etaw_age = current_date - date_in_your_field
     print(str(rec.etaw_age))
```

Please let me know if this what you need

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have edit my question. What I want is something like 1 month 14 days

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at beginning :

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```